# Notepad++ regex - find or remove specific numbers

Tags: regex, numbers, digits

I would like to remove specific numbers from a text file, the list of the numbers are in order from 1 to 192061.
I need to remove a group of numbers, some exemples : "61186","95492","158740","151276","92709"
And my list in total is around of 13k.

I have tried this : (61186)|(95492)|(158740)|(151276)|(92709).
But in the list I have : 61186 and 161186 and it will not match.

Comment: You haven't specified how the list is formatted at all. Is it just one number per line?

Comment: Yes. It's one number per line, and I want to remove specific numbers from the list.

Answer (score 1):

A simple number range generated regex for 1 - 192061 would be:

`(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]\d{0,4}|1[0-8]\d{4}|19[01]\d{3}|1920[0-5]\d|19206[01])(?!\d)`

https://regex101.com/r/YL4GS3/1

It's doubt full you should do it without the look ahead/behind assertions,
but the regex could be re-arrange like this :

`1[0-8]\d{4}|19[01]\d{3}|1920[0-5]\d|19206[01]|[1-9]\d{0,4}`

https://regex101.com/r/7qe299/1

Comment: My list is formated like this.

1
2
3
4
5
...
192061

Comment: Yeah. see https://regex101.com/r/X4QPJP/1 matchin ok ?

Comment: My list is like this : https://regex101.com/r/NA5l8Y/1 . And I want to remove from that list this list of numbers : https://pastebin.com/ktXUy9Nv .

Comment: You'd need this then https://regex101.com/r/Eg3oxt/1

Comment: Or even this quicker version https://regex101.com/r/s0l3DI/1

Comment: A better approach is to run a script. Create an array of int's (flags): `Array Flags[192061]`, then open the list file, get one line at a time, do `index = Atoi(line)` then use the number as an _`index`_ to the array, then set that elements flag: `Flags[_index_] = 1;`. When done with the list file, loop the array for elements not equal to 1: `if ( Flags[counter] != 1) save this one`. Thats all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `^` and `$` anchors to match start/end of the line and use capture group around all the alternatives rather than for each one, e.g.:

```
^(61186|95492|158740|151276|92709|438)$
```

[Demo with your data from a comment](https://regex101.com/r/uxbwiW/1)